# Grails & Terracotta BigMemory

Tags: grails, groovy, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

I've been using Grails with Terracotta DSO by adding ehcache.xml and setting up the Terracotta Server. It works quite well, but I've come along the message that Terracotta doesn't support their Server (OpenSource or DSO however named) any more.

So I've been wondering if anybody tried to replace Terracotta Server with BigMemory, does that work? And if so, which dependencies do I need and where do I get those from?

I'm now using these dependencies:

```
    runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.6.2'
    runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-terracotta:2.6.2'
    runtime 'org.terracotta:terracotta-toolkit-1.6-runtime:5.2.0'
```

Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

BigMemoryMax is a kit (tarball) that includes the latest version of the Terracotta Server.

The latest version is BigMemoryMax 4.1.0 and you can download it from : http://terracotta.org/downloads/bigmemorymax.

You would then need to update your dependencies to have something similar to this :

```
runtime 'net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:2.8.0'
runtime 'org.terracotta:terracotta-toolkit-runtime:4.1.0'
```

Comment: Looks better, I'm now able to start up my grails app and it connects to Terracotta ("Terracotta 4.1.0, as of 20131226-155330 (Revision 33723-24270 by cruise@su10vmo119 from 4.1.0)")

`WARN - Timeout connecting to server: Timeout of 10000 milliseconds occured`

Comment: I'd need to have a look at the full startup log to help you further; I don't know if SO is the best place for that, you could also try http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/forums/show/21.page